# Using Dojo's require.trace to Track Overall Loading Progress

Tags: javascript, dojo, amd

The [docs for Dojo's AMD loader](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/loader/amd.html#tracing) mention a tracing API. Are there any examples of how this is implemented?

I would like to leverage it to show a "Loaded X of X" style message while my app's various dependencies are loaded but I'm not sure how to do so or where to including the tracing in the flow of my code.

**Edit:** It seems that the trace API is only available on the source version of Dojo. Is there a different way of achieving what I want?

Answer (score 1):

This code seems to work but it's too brittle. It relies on 1) require exposing it's inner workings in a source version of Dojo and 2) properties of require that may change in future. Surely there's a better way!

```
require( [], function()
{
    // output amd progress
    var loadWatchHandle = setInterval( function()
    {
        var all = Object.keys( require.modules ).length,
            waiting = 0;

        for( dep in require.waiting )
        {
            if( require.waiting[ dep ] !== 1 )
            {
                waiting++;
            }   
        }

        // write progress
        console.log( ( all - waiting ) + '/' + all + ' files (' + parseInt( ( all - waiting ) / all * 100 ) + '%)' );
    }, 50 );

    require( [ 'dojo/parser',
        'dojo/ready',
        'dijit/layout/BorderContainer',
        'squad_builder/TabContainer',
        'dijit/layout/ContentPane',
        'dojo/domReady!' ], 
    function( parser, ready )
    {
        parser.parse();

        ready( function() // uses ready not domReady because we want initial djits to be parsed
        {
            // stop tracing
            clearInterval( loadWatchHandle );

            // bootstrap here...

        } );
    } );
} );
```